# Activitiy's layout opens more than one?

Tags: android, class, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities connected witdh three layouts. When I call an activity everytime before one collect background. eg. I am on the mainactivity then, I call B then call main again  when I am on B, after that I call B and this sitution if I click back on screen B, it comes B>main>B>main or something like such as B>A>main>A>main>B>main...

```
private Intent intent_Main;
.
.
.
intent_Main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent_Main);
```

This is my code for calling activities, for B `(this, B.class)` like that...

I want when I click back on different from main it just turn main and when main shows it exit -not show previously activity screens-...

Edit:
How can I close all screen (exit) on main activity and how can I return just main activity from others?

[If I go to B.class and its screen then go to main activity (with button etc.) and then again B, after that I click back I return Main activity then push again return first B and then click back it returns first time openin mainactivity after that it close]

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting a `new Intent` to go to your Activty Main each time you're in your Activity B just call `finish()`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

or in manifest use

```
android:launchmode="singleTop"
```

Comment: I guess it works to.
singleTop means everytime when I back mainactivity or I go to B then A and click back when A is shown it turns just B and then closing or A to main?

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
finish();
```

If you don't want to have the user return to an activity after starting a new activity using `startActivity()`.

The following code starts a new activity and then calls `finish()` to exit the current activity:

```
          Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
          Intent intent = new Intent( ctx, MainActivity.class );

          // Start our real activity
          startActivity( intent  );

          // Finish this activity so user doesn't return via back button
          finish();
```

Comment: I do not use context that I do not know it. I just saw `this` for intent. Is there any difference and which one is better?

Comment: That is an excellent question that unfortunately isn't answered anywhere with absolute certainty.  [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) Android Developer's blog discusses the difference and gives some guidance, but doesn't give an absolute answer, other than saying "to avoid context-related memory leaks" "Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity".  FYI, `this` is the activity-level context and `getApplicationContext()` returns the applicaiton-level context.